# check if callback is registered with angular's deferred object

Tags: angularjs, promise, deferred

I would like to add callback for angular's `$q.defer()` with `then` only if there no callbacks registered already.

The question is how can I check whether callbacks are registered with this deferred object or not ?

Comment: could you please elaborate more on this.?

Comment: That really sounds like an XY problem. What problem are you trying to solve by doing that?

Comment: I'm using angular's $http service, like this:
``javascript
var deferred = $q.defer();
var promise = self.$http(httpconfig);
promise.success(function(res){
    deferred.resolve(res);
}).error(function(error){
if(deferred has no error callback){
//do some global error handling ONLY if there's no error callback is registered with my deferred 
    alert(error);
}else{

   deferred.reject();
});
```